# How would I push a negative number with OPCODES onto the stack?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

If the user wants to push -10 onto the stack.

Would I do "10 OP_NEGATE" ?

Or could I convert it to the hex value by doing 0x80 + 10 = 0X8A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will work. OP_NEGATE simply XORs with 0x80, so you can also directly push the result.

Comment: And we take the absolute value of a signed integer right? In this case 10 could be written with one byte so I think that using two bytes was overkill?

Comment: Not necessarily. Some operations, like hashing, will produce different results for positive or negative numbers. Some operations, like signatures, will fail if the R value is negative. It depends on what you're doing.

Comment: Take into account that for numbers between -1 and 16 inclusive, short 1-byte opcodes exist. Pushing any other number (like -10) requires an explicit push operation of the bytes encoding of the number. Both "10 NEGATE" and "-10" are therefore 2-byte scripts.